# Error: static class forcing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, jna

I have a class that contains a static method for execute a external program using `CreateProcess` api from JNA (Java NAtive Access).

*PS:* I'm making based in this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828607/how-to-run-chrome-using-jna) in SO.

My trouble is that when put `ProcessInformation` class and `StartupInfoA` as static classes for use this in method described above, this forces a `@Override` of type:

```
        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

And I never have success for execute my project :-(. See:

[image]

So, i ask to you: - Exist some solution for it?

Here is how i'm making all process for obtain my goal:

```
package myProgram;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.SW_SHOWNORMAL;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import java.util.List;


public class Execute {

    public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);

    boolean CreateProcessA(
             String lpApplicationName
            , String lpCommandLine
            , Structure lpProcessAttributes
            , Structure lpThreadAttributes
            , boolean bInheritHandles
            , int dwCreationFlags
            , Structure lpEnvironment
            , String lpCurrentDirectory
            , Structure lpStartupInfo
            , Structure lpProcessInformation);
}

public static class ProcessInformation extends Structure {
    public Pointer hProcess;
    public Pointer hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

public static class StartupInfoA extends Structure {
    public int cb;
    public WString lpReserved;
    public WString lpDesktop;
    public WString lpTitle;
    public int dwX;
    public int dwY;
    public int dwXSize;
    public int dwYSize;
    public int dwXCountChars;
    public int dwYCountChars;
    public int dwFillAttribute;
    public int dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public Pointer lpReserved2;
    public Pointer hStdInput;
    public Pointer hStdOutput;
    public Pointer hStdError;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

public static void ExecuteProc(String software){

        ProcessInformation processInformation = new ProcessInformation();
        StartupInfoA startupInfo = new StartupInfoA(); 
        startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

        Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessA(software, null
                , null
                , null
                , true
                , 0
                , null
                , null
                , startupInfo
                , processInformation);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you remove the`throw new UnsupportedOperationException` statement in `ProcessInformation` and replace it with `return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "hProcess", "hThread", "dwProcessId", "dwThreadId" });` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @CKing, this your suggestion returns other error exception, [see](http://pastebin.com/zsQb93uP).

Comment: Well, I asked you to paste that line in `ProcessInformation` class. You should not paste the same line in `StartupInfoA` because it has different set of fields. The `getFieldOrder` method must return the names of the fields that appear in the class in the order they appear. So for `StartupInfoA`, you need return the names of the fields that are in `StartupInfoA`! Does that make sense?

Comment: @CKing, thank you, but yours suggestion unfortunately don't are working :-(. You can provide a answer with your example, please?

Comment: I am sorry. This is the best I can do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `getFieldOrder` method is to provide the names and the order in which fields appear in a class that represents a `Structure`. You need to do the following :

**ProcessInformation**

Replace the `getFieldOrder` method as follows :

```
  @Override
  protected List getFieldOrder() {
      return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "hProcess", "hThread", "dwProcessId", "dwThreadId" });
  }
```

Similarly for `StartupInfoA`, return a list containing the names of the fields in `StartupInfoA` in the order in which they appear.